# What does "of its own too-much" mean in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can we use "too-much" as a noun? (Shouldn't it be "too-much-ness?) Then, does "of its own too-much" mean "because of being too much" in the following context?

> Since then I have lived to see state after state extirpate its wolves. I have watched the face of many a newly wolfless mountain, and seen the south-facing slopes wrinkle with a maze of new deer trails. I have seen every edible bush and seedling browsed, first to anaemic desuetude, and then to death. I have seen every edible tree defoliated to the height of a saddlehorn. Such a mountain looks as if someone had given God a new pruning shears, and forbidden Him all other exercise. In the end the starved bones of the hoped-for deer herd, dead **of its own too-much**, bleach with the bones of the dead sage, or molder under the high-lined junipers.

Context: [*Thinking Like a Mountain* By Aldo Leopold](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Answer (score 1):

"Of its own two-much" (noun) here means

> of its own excess OR of its own over-population

It reminds me of the children's book, "The Berenstain Bears and Too Much Birthday."

Your proposed word, "too-much-ness," wasn't needed in this passage, at least.  However, you are welcome to try to write something that you think requires adding *-ness* and see if people buy it.

However, in case you aren't familiar with it, I should tell you of the existing phrase

> too much of a muchness

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I wrote "OR" in the way I would when proposing two different restatements or two different translations.

Comment: I find it misleading. There is only one meaning here. Your formulation suggests there are two alternative ones.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Do you see "excess" and "over-population" as two different meanings?  If so, which one do you consider "correct"?  // Your approach feels to me like a creativity killer....

Comment: I believe I made myself clear. Please refrain from personal remarks.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I have said nothing about you, only about the approach you took here.  Please forgive me if it appeared otherwise.

Comment: Starting at the title Thinking Like a Mountain, we know the author is writing with poetic beauty. So it can be hard to pin him down on meaning. His argument is that vilifying and killing wolves upsets the balance of nature, with unexpected consequences even for its prey, the deer. The good news that the wolves are dead is just too good to digest.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I'm with you until your last sentence, where you veer off into, in my opinion, an interpretation that is 100% off base.

Comment: Adding 'too much of a muchness' into the mix is confusing. While 'muchness' does mean 'greatness in quantity or degree'; '*much* of a muchness' means 'very similar'. '*Too* much of a muchness' would mean the objects were were *too similar* for some purpose, not that they were too great in quantity or degree. So I don't see any connection to the OP.

Comment: @Spagirl - I wanted to make OP aware of a word and a phrase that are similar to what was proposed.  // "Too much of a muchness" does get used sometimes.  If googling for this phrase doesn't convince you, one of us could write a Question and I could write an Answer.